# H is contained in K if f (K)=kH=N and N is a normal subgroup of G/H?

Tags: group-theory

The question comes from the problem that the $H$ is a maximal normal subgroup of $G$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $G/H$ is simple. 
The overall proof is mostly done, but I feel some difficulty to understand the why does H contain in $K$ if f($K$)=$N$ and $N$ is a subgroup of the quotient group $G/H$. I am going to use this result to generate the "if" part use contradiction. I have already proved the converse part. 
It might be weird to stuck at such a strange place. 
Thanks for your help.

Since I have only learnt the 1-3 isomorphism theorem, I really don't have any idea about the fourth one. But I hope by the primary knowledge I could solve the problem.

Comment: Try to prove that the subgroups contain a normal subgroup $H$ is in one to one correspondence with the subgroups of $G/H$. I assume you hypothesize $H\subset K\subset G$, and $f$ is the quotient map. Your question can be answered directly if you notice $H$ is normal in $K$ as well.

Comment: Please edit your question to indicate what $f$ stands for. Also please edit to clarify whether "why does $H$ contain in $K$" means "why does $H$ contain $K$" or "why is $H$ contained in $K$".

Answer (score 2):

If you know the fundamental correspondence between subgroups of $G$ that contain $H$ and subgroups of $G/H$, then that should be sufficient. The key point is that this correspondence preserves normality and is sometimes called the [third isomorphism theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorems) or the [fourth isomorphism theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_theorem).